# Why am I getting the combined score of different fields instead of the score of the best matching field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to find the best matching field out of different mutifield documents by using multi_match with best_fields and a custom analyzer with shingles and/or ngrams applied to every field.  I expect get the score of the best matching field but instead I get the combined score of the different fields of the best matching document. Why is this happening? Is there a different way to do it?  Can somebody please tell me how can I get the score of only the best matching field?

This is an example of what I am doing:

```
PUT /my-index1
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name1": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "name_shingles": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "shingle_analyz",
              "search_analyzer": "shingle_analyz"
            }
          }
        },
        "name2": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "name_shingles": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "shingle_analyz",
              "search_analyzer": "shingle_analyz"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "1",
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "shingle_filter": {
            "max_shingle_size": "3",
            "min_shingle_size": "2",
            "output_unigrams": false,
            "type": "shingle"
          },
          "duplicate_token_filter": {
            "type": "unique",
            "only_on_same_position": false
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "shingle_analyz": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding",
              "shingle_filter",
              "duplicate_token_filter"
            ],
            "char_filter": [
              "my_char_filter"
            ]
          }
        },
        "char_filter": {
          "my_char_filter": {
            "type": "mapping",
            "mappings": [
              "'s => s",
              "'S => S"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "number_of_replicas": "1"
    }
  }
}
 

PUT /my-index1/_doc/1
{
  "name1": "WA WA WA WOMAN",
  "name2": "wa wa"
}

PUT /my-index1/_doc/2
{
  "name1": "WA WA WOMAN",
  "name2": "help"
}

PUT /my-index1/_doc/3
{
  "name1": "the great showman",
  "name2": "WA WA WOMAN"
}


GET my-index1/_search
{
  "explain": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "name1.name_shingles",
              "name2.name_shingles"
            ],
            "query": "WA WA WOMAN",
            "type": "best_fields",
            "operator": "or"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research I come up with the conclusion that match and muti_match queries produce unreliable scores when working with shingles and multiple fields. I tried many different configurations and I always get the scores of different fields mixed up.